# Need some help converting between two .NET instances

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

I'm having trouble trying to convert one instance to another instance type. I thought, via inheritence, that this should just work.

Here's the error message. (sorry it's hard to read - open it in a new tab)

[image]

And here's the context.

```
public interface IItem { ... }

public class AuctionItem : IItem { ... }

public class BuyNowItem : IItem { ... }

public class SearchResult<T> where T : IItem
{
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

So we have 2 concrete classes, which both implement the `IItem` interface and a result class which contains a list of `IItems`.

Now, how do we use this? We define a searching interface...

```
public interface ISearchService<T, in TU>
    where T : IItem
    where TU : ISearchOptions
{
    string Name { get; }
    Task<SearchResult<T>> SearchAsync(TU searchOptions);
}
```

So here we can see that we can search something (eg. eBay) and it will return some results (eg `IItems`).

How do I implement this? Now, I have a crazy method that looks like this....

```
public class FooSearchService<T, TU> : ISearchService<T, TU>
    where T : AuctionItem, new()
    where TU : AuctionSearchOptions
{
    public async Task<SearchResult<T>> SearchAsync(TU searchOptions) { .. }
}
```

Seems to be working fine so far ....

Until i now try this ....

```
<my console app .. and yes, i'm not awaiting this call, etc...>
private SearchResult<IItem> DoSearches(Notification notification)
{
    if (ebay)
    {
        var searchResult = _ebaySearchService.SearchAsync(auctionSearchOptions);
        return searchResult.Result;  // ** COMPILE ERROR HERE
    }
    else if (somethingElse_eg_BuyNow_1)
    { 
        ... 
        return buyNowSearchResult.Result;
    }
}
```

See what I'm trying to do? I'm trying to say: Search ebay and return the `AuctionItem` search results. Or try another service and return their `BuyNowItem`'s ...

I thought that, because the ebay returns a `SearchResult<AuctionItem>`, the calling method wants to return a `SearchResut<IItem>` which `AuctionItem` implements, so I assumed it would be ok. But it's not :(

Can anyone offer any assistance?

#### Update

Nearly got it all working now :) The answer from @jdphenix basically made it work. The only problem is that I'm trying to return a `Task<..>` and that's not working. Here's the error message for that..

[image]

Comment: Wild guess without looking too close at your question: take a look at [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: To add to @poke's pointed, try `ISearchService<out T, in TU>` and `FooSearchService<out T, in TU>`.

Comment: @Noseratio Only interfaces may be declared with Covariance and Contravariance.

Comment: @Lukazoid, correct, I overlooked `FooSearchService<out T, in TU>` is not an interface. So it needs to be made an interface `IFooSearchService<out T, in TU>`, and then `FooSearchService` should be derived from it.

Comment: (for the concrete class), `T` is an `AuctionItem` which inherits from `IItem` ... The `ISearchService` defines `T` as an `IItem`.

Comment: @Noseratio it doesn't compile. Error message is the image, above in main post.

Comment: I think I need to make a repo solution of this ... for people to grok / test, this easily.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, please do, as a small console app. Just use http://dotnetfiddle.net and update your question.

Comment: I always forget about DNF.net ! Awesome mate :) will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface IItem { }

public class AuctionItem : IItem { }

public class BuyNowItem : IItem { }

public interface IResult<out T> where T : IItem {
  IList<IItem> Items { get; set; }
  int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult<T> : IResult<T> where T : IItem
{
  public IList<IItem> Items { get; set; }
  public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

You are unable to return a `SearchResult<AuctionItem>` from `DoSearches()` because then this would be possible:

```
List<BuyNowItem> items = new List<SearchResult<BuyNowItem>>();
items.Add(DoSearches()); // Could be a SeachResult<AuctionItem>
```

What does the interface `IResult` do?

- `<out T>` declares that any type implementing `IResult` will have `T` as an output. Consequently, you can do something like `IResult<IItem> result = DoSearches()` and it be valid.
- `IList<IItem>` instead of `IList<T>` because the compiler can't prove that every `T` would be a type safe conversion to `IItem`. The fuller explanation of this would require someone which much more expertise than me.

A new `DoSearches()` could conceptually be this:

```
private IResult<IItem> DoSearches(Notification notification) {
  var searchresult = _ebaySearchService.SearchAsync(auctionSearchOptions);
  return searchresult;
}
```

Comment: `var searchresult = _ebaySearchService(); ` <-- a result equals an .. instance? .. is that missing a method call?

Comment: @Pure.Krome sorry I don't understand your question, `_ebaySearchService()` is just a dummy method I used, its signature is `private SearchResult<AuctionItem> _ebaySearchService()`

Comment: i'v enearly got it now ... could u please show me how to add the result to a list of `Task`'s please? So i can then do `Task.WhenAll(tasks);`